# django-URL inside anchor tag becomes relative to the current page django

Tags: html, django, anchor

**urls.py**

```
    path('add_a_product_to_store/<store_id>',views.add_a_product_to_store,name='add_a_product_to_store'),
    path('show_a_store/<store_id>', views.show_a_store,name='show_a_store')
```

**show_a_store.html**

```
<a href="add_a_product_to_store/5">Add a product</a>
```

When user enters `ip:port/show_a_store/5` .  . . . `show_a_store.html` is shown.
But the link inside anchor tag points to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/show_a_store/add_a_product_to_store/5` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_a_product_to_store/5`

How to make  it point to actual url irrespective of current page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add slash as shown below

```
path('add_a_product_to_store/<store_id>/',views.add_a_product_to_store,name='add_a_product_to_store'),
path('show_a_store/<store_id>/', views.show_a_store,name='show_a_store')
```

and template

```
<a href="{% url 'add_a_product_to_store' store_id=object.id %}">Add a product</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag

```
<a href="{% url 'add_a_product_to_store' store_id=5 %}">Add a product</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.
I committed a mistake in html.
When using anchor tag,`<a href="foo/">` means **`ip:port/url-of-current-page/foo/...`
But
`<a href="/foo/">`
means `ip:port/foo/`
If there is no `forward slash (/)` at the beginning of url,it is treated as a relative url and url of current page is appended to the url.